# Regular expression to extract first word + first character of all following words

Tags: r, regex

I am (newbie) using R and regular Regular expression to write the regex for manipulating strings in a `data.frame` column. My data look like this in R:

```
c1                       
Peter Parker            
Hawk & Dove             
J Jonah Jameson         
3JPX spo                
Bruce Wayne
```

What I am trying to get is 2nd column "c2" that consists of the following strings:

```
c2
PeterP
Hawk&D
JJJ
3JPXs
BruceW
```

Basically I want the entire first word of the string (regardless of length) and the first alphanumeric element of every word after. I have not been able to find any function or logic for this. Is it possible to do so with regex?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: BTW, do you mean to have `c2` from `c1`, or is that a typo?

Comment: Yeah. I want the values in column c2 to be derived from the values in column c1

Comment: Ahhh, column names. I did not assume that that was a `data.frame` or `matrix`. At times, it can be both useful (to us) and absolutely clear to provide data in a more unambiguous format, such as programmatically with `data.frame(...)` or with `dput(x)`; while the latter does not look as awesome, it can gives a completely-identical object with the least effort (on our part).

Comment: I did actually say it was a data.frame column in the question title. But next time onwards i'll use 'data.frame(...)' notation as well. :) thanks

Comment: Bad on me, thanks. (I find multi-line titles to be a bit busy, so I must have skimmed too quickly. I'll try better next time :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a base R approach using `gsub`:

```
x <- c("Peter Parker", "Hawk & Dove", "J Jonah Jameson", "3JPX spo", "Bruce Wayne")
output <- gsub("\\s+(\\S)\\S*(?!\\S)", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
output

[1] "PeterP" "Hawk&D" "JJJ"    "3JPXs"  "BruceW"
```

The regex pattern `\s+(\S)\S*(?!\S)` matches one or more space characters, then matches and captures the first character of the name component.  It also consumes the remainder of the name component, replacing with only the captured first character.

In case the above still be unclear to you, here is how the regex pattern works, step by step:

```
\s+    match one or more space characters
(\S)   then match AND capture the first character of the name-word
\S*    match the remainder of the name-word
(?!\S) assert that what follows the end of the name-word is either a space
       or the end of the string
```

The replacement in the call to `gsub` is just `\1`, which is the first and only capture group, corresponding to the first letter of each name, beyond the very first name.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly.Just out of curiosity- is there a word limit to number of words in string it will work on?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your comment.  Can you show me one of the current inputs along with how you want it to look under your new requirements?

Comment: for example - Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore -> AlbusPWBD. Would the above approach work on 5 words or longer string as well?

Comment: @JohnR Yes, it would work on names consisting of any number of name words.  Try it out.  The `g` in `gsub` means "global" replacement, so it covers all words.

Comment: JohnR, have you tried it? Especially with as short as Tim's solution is, it would take you less time to *try* it on that name than to type the question ... and then you have to wait for the reply.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen -- you did start your answer with `sub`, not `gsub` ...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen@r2evans I did try it. But since i have > 1000 rows it'll take time to check them if it worked perfectly. Most of the rows have less than 3 words in a string, so i think for them it will work perfectly. I am just worried about strings with >3 words.

Comment: ok Just checked. it works with 5 words too. thanks a lot guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Though not particularly a regex solution but a different approach could be to get bring data in long format by separating each word, get first word as it is and take only first character from remaining of the words and paste them.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(c1, sep = "\\s+") %>%
  summarise(c2 = paste0(first(c1) , paste0(substr(c1[-1], 1, 1), collapse = "")),
            c1 = paste(c1, collapse = " ")) %>%
  select(c1, c2, -row)

#   c1              c2    
#  <chr>           <chr> 
#1 Peter Parker    PeterP
#2 Hawk & Dove     Hawk&D
#3 J Jonah Jameson JJJ   
#4 3JPX spo        3JPXs 
#5 Bruce Wayne     BruceW
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(c1 = c("Peter Parker", "Hawk & Dove", "J Jonah Jameson", 
"3JPX spo", "Bruce Wayne")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

The development version of *unglue* features a `multiple` argument, which can be a function to apply to identically named matches (here we'd want to concatenate them with `paste0()`). In our case we want to match the full first word, then the first character of all sequences separated by space, and we have either 1 or 2 of such sequences following the first word:

```
# remotes::install_github("moodymudskipper/unglue")
library(unglue)
patterns <- c(
  "{c2} {c2=\\S}{=\\S*} {c2=\\S}{=\\S*}",
  "{c2} {c2=\\S}{=\\S*}")

unglue_data(df$c1, patterns, multiple = paste0)
#>       c2
#> 1 PeterP
#> 2 Hawk&D
#> 3    JJJ
#> 4  3JPXs
#> 5 BruceW
```